# Как сделать секундомер с handler на Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

В процессе написания приложения "секундомер" на Kotlin, столкнулся с вопросом, как правильно использовать Handler на Kotlin.
Мои варианты использования к успеху не привели, и самостоятельно разобраться с ошибкой не могу.
Суть приложения в том, что при нажатии на кнопку play, запускается секундомер, т.е. начинает работать handler, но этого не происходит.

Вариант 1:

```
    private fun runTimer(){

        Handler().postDelayed({  var hours: Int = sec / 3600
            var minutes: Int = (sec % 3600) / 60
            var secs: Int = sec % 60
            var time: String = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), 
    "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secs)
            textViewTimer.text = time
            if (isRunning) { //При нажатии на кнопку "Play" переменной isRunning
                sec++        //присвается значение "true" и секунды должны увеличиваться
        }}, 1000)
   }
```

Вариант 2:

```
    private fun runTimer(){
        var handler = Handler()
        var runnable: Runnable = Runnable {
            var hours: Int = sec / 3600
            var minutes: Int = (sec % 3600) / 60
            var secs: Int = sec % 60
            var time: String = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secs)
            textViewTimer.text = time
            if (isRunning) {//При нажатии на кнопку "Play" переменной isRunning
                sec++        //присвается значение "true" и секунды должны увеличиваться
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще в kotlin насколько я знаю есть функция для решения данного вопроса:

```
val timer = object: CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {...}

    override fun onFinish() {...}
}
timer.start()
```

Либо второй вариант - сделать все через вьюшки созданные как раз для этого:

```
<Chronometer 
        android:id="@+id/c_meter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="256dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#092FEC"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

и дальше из активности:

```
val meter = findViewById<Chronometer>(R.id.c_meter) 
meter.start() // meter.stop()
```

Вот есть [туториал](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chronometer-in-kotlin/) как сделать секундомер. И [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095875/kotlin-simple-countdown-timer) есть обсуждения как сделать на котлин.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!